# Ranking results: manually breaking the tie

Tags: sql-server-2008, ranking

I used this page: [Ranking Criteria](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx)

To write this:

```
with cte as (
Select t.[Client ID]
      ,t.[Location]
      ,Count(t.[Location]) [Loc Count]
FROM #tmp_PCL_coreData t
Group By  t.[Client ID]
        , t.[Location])

Select *
      ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte b
        WHERE a.[Client ID] = b.[Client ID] AND a.[Loc Count] <= b.[Loc Count]) [Rank]
FROM cte a
```

And it works fine for giving me ranked locations for each `[Client ID]`.  The only downside is that when the `[Loc Count]` is the same for each `[Location]` then the rank is the same for each.  In my particular case I need to arbitrarily assign one or the other with the "better" rank.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Example:

[image]

You can see that Client 60756 has 1 each in Redmond and Bellevue, giving both values a Rank 2.  Either one can be Rank 1 for my purposes, but I definitely need a rank 1.  For now, it makes sense for me to assign rank 1 alphabetically so that if I come up with a better tie-breaking criteria later I can see where to build that logic in.

Comment: If you are using 2008 why are you using approaches from 2000? Instead of count where loc count <= loc count you could use ROW_NUMBER() and easily break the tie by additionally ordering by Location.

Comment: Ah!  `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Client ID] ORDER BY [Loc Count] DESC) [Rank]`  Problem solved!

Comment: To answer your question, I'm pretty new at this and some solutions seem more logical to me at the outset.  This is why the online community is better than any classroom.